# Join models in findall active record yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am writing a function to get posts and ordered by the number of likes.

I can do it fine in pure SQL, but I wanted to have it written in the yii way.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static function getPopularPosts($limit) {
    $posts = Tip::model()
        ->with( array(
            'Like' => array(
                'select' => 'sum(`Like`.value) as likes',
                'join' => 'LEFT JOIN `Like` ON `Tip`.idTip = `Like`.relatedTableIdFK',
                'condition'=>'`Like`.relatedTableName like "Tip" AND `Like`.status=1',
        )));
    $posts ->together();
    $posts ->findAll(array(
        'group'=>'idTip',
        'order'=>'likes DESC',
        'limit' => $limit,
    ));
    return $posts;
}
```

And the get the error:

> Relation "Like" is not defined in active record class "Tip".

Comment: Relations used in 'with' property has to be defined in model class.

Answer (score 0):

Read first please http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Then open your model Tip find method `relations` or create new and add there relation according to documentation above.

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'Like'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Like', 'relatedTableIdFK')
    );
}
```